# How do i get input from website with node and after send it to database

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I am haveing problem with getting input from  my website send it so node (server.js) and the value to database. I already have done database connection and it works but value of input was undefined, so i have found out that i dont know how to get the input from the webpage (store.ejs).
So if someone could help.
"I am making eshop for my self".

store.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Store</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/logo.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" defer></script>
    <script>
      var stripePublicKey = '<%= stripePublicKey %>'
    </script>
<script src="script.js" defer></script>
<!--<script src="../billing.js" defer></script>-->








<link rel="icon" href="/images/logo.png">
</head>
<body>
<!--  <a href="cart.html"><img src="cart-logo.png" id="cart-logo" style="background-color: #eee;border-radius: 50%;"></a> -->
    <span id="logo2">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="/images/logo.png" style="border-radius: 50%; width: 100px; position: relative; right: 0%; left: 50%;"></a>
        </span>
  <div id="navigator1">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='store'>Store</a></li>
      <li><a href="aboutus.html"> About us</a></li>
      <!--<li><a href='tshirtjacket.html'></a></li>-->
      <!--<li><a href='other.html'></a></li>-->
      <!--<li><a href=''>Other</a></li>-->
      <!--<li><a href=''>Other</a></li>-->
      <div class="img2">
        <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/bonekicks/"><img src="/images/instagram-logo.png" id="img2"></a></li>
        </div>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id="navigator1"></div>
<section class="container content-section">
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Store</h1>
<br>
<div></div>
<div class="shop-items">
    <% items.boot.forEach(function(item){ %>
        <div class="shop-item" data-item-id="<%= item.id %>">
            <span class="shop-item-title"><%= item.name %></span>
            <img class="shop-item-image" src="/images/<%= item.imgName %>">
            <div class="shop-item-details">
                <span class="shop-item-price">$<%= item.price / 100 %></span>
                <span class=""><%= item.quantity%> in stock</span>
                <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% }) %> 
  
  </div>
</div>
</section>

<section class="container content-section">
<h2 class="section-header">CART</h2>
<div class="cart-row">
  <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">ITEM</span>
  <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">PRICE</span>
  <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">QUANTITY</span>
</div>
<div class="cart-items">
</div>
<div class="cart-total">
  <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
  <span class="cart-total-price">$0</span>
</div>

<form action="../server.js" method="POST" id="billing">
  <div class="form-group" id="billing1">
    <label for="state"><!--State--></label>
    <input type="text" id="state" placeholder="State: " name="state">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="address"><!--Address--></label>
    <input type="text" id="address" placeholder="Address: " name="address">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><!--Zip code--></label>
    <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" placeholder="Zip code: ">
  </div>        
 



<button class="btn btn-primary btn-purchase" onclick="clicked()" type="button">PURCHASE</button>
</form>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

server.js

````
    require('dotenv').config()
}

const stripeSecretKey = process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
const stripePublicKey = process.env.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY

//console.log(stripeSecretKey, stripePublicKey)

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const fs = require('fs')
const stripe = require('stripe')(stripeSecretKey)




var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var flash = require('express-flash');
var session = require('express-session');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var http = require('http'); 





app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session({ 
    secret: '123456catr',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }
}))
 
app.use(flash());










var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "bonekicks"
  });
  
  
  
   

    










app.get('/store', function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('items.json', function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            res.status(500).end()
        } else {
            res.render('store.ejs', {
                stripePublicKey: stripePublicKey,
                items: JSON.parse(data)
            })
            
            
    



        }
    })
})


app.post('/purchase', function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('items.json', function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            res.status(500).end()
        } else {
            const itemsJson = JSON.parse(data)
            const itemsArray = itemsJson.boot
            let total = 0
            
            
            
            
            req.body.items.forEach(function(item){
                const itemJson = itemsArray.find(function(a){
                    return a.id == item.id
                    
                })
                total = total + itemJson.price * item.quantity
                console.log(Date())
                console.log("id of product: " + itemJson.id + "; quantity: " + item.quantity + " "+ total)
               
                console.log("//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////")
                
            })
  


            stripe.charges.create({
                amount: total,
                source: req.body.stripeTokenId,
                currency: 'usd',
                
                

            }).then(function(){
                console.log('Charge Succesful')
                res.json({message: 'Successfully purchased items ;)'})
                
               
                
                var state1 = req.body.state;
                var address = req.body.address;
                var zip = req.body.zip;
               var state;
             



             


           

                con.connect(function(err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    

                    var sql = `INSERT INTO customers (c_state, c_address, c_zip) VALUES ("${state1}", "${address}", "${zip}")`;
                    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
                      if (err) throw err;
                      
                      console.log("1 record inserted, ID: " + result.insertId);
                      //console.log(state + " " + address + " " + zip);
                    });
                  });
                  
                
          
                


                
                

                  
            
            }).catch(function(){
                console.log('Charge Fail')
                res.status(500).end()
            })
            
            

            



        }
    })
})

  

app.listen(3000)```


and script.js whitch is used by store.ejs
````

and script.js whitch is used by store.ejs

```
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
    ready()
}



function ready() {
    var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')
    for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    }
    
    var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')
    for (var i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
        var input = quantityInputs[i]
        input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
    }

    var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-button')
    for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = addToCartButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked)
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked)
}



var stripeHandler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: stripePublicKey,
    locale: 'auto',
    token: function(token) {
        var items = []
        var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
        var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
        for (var a = 0; a < cartRows.length; a++) {
            var cartRow = cartRows[a]
            var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]
            var quantity = quantityElement.value
            var id = cartRow.dataset.itemId
            items.push({
                id: id,
                quantity: quantity
            })
        }

        fetch('/purchase', {
            method: 'POST', 
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                stripeTokenId: token.id,
                items: items
            })
        }).then(function(res){
            return res.json()
        }).then(function(data){
            alert(data.message)
            var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
            while (cartItems.hasChildNodes()) {
                cartItems.removeChild(cartItems.firstChild)
            }
            updateCartTotal()
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.error(error)
        })
    }
})


function purchaseClicked() {
    
    var priceElement = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0]
    var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', '')) * 100
    stripeHandler.open({
        amount: price
    })

    
    

    
}

function removeCartItem(event) {
    var buttonClicked = event.target
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
    updateCartTotal()
}

function quantityChanged(event) {
    var input = event.target
    if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
        input.value = 1
    }
    updateCartTotal()
}

function addToCartClicked(event) {
    var button = event.target
    var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement
    var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText
    var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText
    var imageSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-image')[0].src
    var id = shopItem.dataset.itemId
    addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc, id)
    updateCartTotal()
}

function addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc, id) {
    var cartRow = document.createElement('div')
    cartRow.classList.add('cart-row')
    cartRow.dataset.itemId = id
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-title')
    for (var i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++) {
        if (cartItemNames[i].innerText == title) {
            alert('This item is already added to the cart')
            return
        }
    }
    var cartRowContents = `
        <div class="cart-item cart-column">
            <img class="cart-item-image" src="${imageSrc}" width="100" height="100">
            <span class="cart-item-title">${title}</span>
        </div>
        <span class="cart-price cart-column">${price}</span>
        <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
            <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
        </div>`
    cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents
    cartItems.append(cartRow)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')[0].addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0].addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
}

function updateCartTotal() {
    var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
    var total = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
        var cartRow = cartRows[i]
        var priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
        var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]
        var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', ''))
        var quantity = quantityElement.value
        total = total + (price * quantity)
    }
    total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100
    document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0].innerText = '$' + total
}
```

[Image of directory tree - If needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j1Zg.png)